# Abrir banco Progress

Tags: banco-de-dados, importação, progress-bar

Boa tarde, preciso abrir um banco de dados Progress de um cliente para fazer uma importação e não estou conseguindo. Preciso de uma ajuda para saber alguma forma de trabalhar com esse banco, seja por código ou aplicações.

estes são os arquivos obtidos do cliente:

[image]

Comment: Cara, tu não tem o arquivo de `backup` do banco?

Comment: O que recebi foram esses arquivos, como obtenho um arquivo de backup?

Comment: Fazendo um backup do banco, sinceramente eu não sei o que são esses arquivos da imagem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu vai precisar ter o Progress na maquina.

Quando instalado vai em Data Administration -> Database -> Connect.
Informe o caminho do "*.db" e com isso já estará conectado com o banco. Depois só usar o Data Dictionary para visualizar as tabelas e os campos.

Fora isso acho que não há nenhum interpretador de Banco Progress

Answer (score 2):

Para abrir o banco vai precisar do Progress. Em seguida editar o info.st, inserindo o caminho do banco onde esta gravado. 
Executar prostrct repair info info.st para reparar o banco no local.
Em seguida abrir pelo prowin32.exe, menu Tools, Datadictionary e conectar o banco, inserindo o local do mesmo apenas.

Comment: Quando aparecer mais alguma situação em que eu precise abrir um banco em progress, eu tentarei utilizar essa sua alternativa, muito obrigado!